# How to list all apps on WAS and their linked node cell and server name?

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

The context is that I have a script that automates the update or deployment of applications on WAS 6.1 servers from a DMGR. This script use a setting file that contains the application name, the server cell, node and name. I don't want to make manually a file for every application. I searched IBM for a way to get all these informations and can't find how.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Ftxml_listapp.html

I know how to list apps on a server but I need to link all those infos together.

$AdminApp list (any options would give me info I need?)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [scriptLibrary](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rxml_7libapp1.html) included in WAS version 8:

```
AdminApplication.listApplications()
```

Returns: List of the available application names in the respective cell.